# Implement .NET redirect to Angular's URL

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, redirect

I have ASP.NET WEB API & Angular SPA.

For authentication purposes (once it's done, actually), I have to make a redirect from backend to some front end uri.

Currently backend routes are configured to be on, i.e.

```
http://localhost:6004/company/api
```

While SPA is

```
http://localhost:9000/company/#/
```

How can I overcome ports here and redirect from, i.e.

```
http://localhost:6004/company/api/MyController
```

to

```
http://localhost:9000/company/#/redirectinsidespa
```

Solution should also work when application is hosted at some url, not just localhost.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it'll be more convenient use angular route html5Mode.

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode({ enabled: true,
       requireBase: false});
```

Hope, it helps.
Best Regards,
Roman.